# Error reflashing Nexus S to stock Jelly Bean

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-nexus-s, vanilla-android

I've got a Nexus S (D720) running CM 10.1.3, and I'd like to flash it back over to Google's [latest factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) (sojus-jro03r). When I try updating, I get the following:

```
sending 'bootloader' (1536 KB)...
OKAY [  0.195s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.347s]
finished. total time: 0.542s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
sending 'radio' (15232 KB)...
OKAY [  2.037s]
writing 'radio'...
OKAY [ 15.314s]
finished. total time: 17.350s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: D720SPRKE1
Baseband Version.....: D720SPRXXX
Serial Number........: 3730DA5FBAF300EC
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.001s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
checking version-baseband...
FAILED

Device version-baseband is 'D720SPRXXX'.
Update requires 'D720SPRKC9' or 'D720SPRKD8' or 'D720SPRKE5' or 'D720SPRKH1'.

finished. total time: 0.006s
```

Searching "D720SPRXXX" on Google gets exactly zero hits. How did my baseband version get like that, and how do I change it to make Google's update happy?

It's worth noting that the device *still boots* into CyanogenMod without issues, and can be reflashed with a *new* version of CyanogenMod; I just can't install Google's factory image.

Answer (score 1):

what I found was that flash_all.sh actually updates the baseband version with the radio image. but rebooting from fastboot to fastboot again does not show the update in the baseband version.
so manually reboot the phone to normal boot, and try one more time going to fastboot and do the update.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the phone fixed, but I still don't know what actually caused the problem. Here's what I did:

I was using the "sojus-jro03r" image. I assume the same will work with any other. Once I unzipped the archive, there's a file called `image-sojus-jro03r.zip` inside that contains the OS image. Inside *that* archive is a file called `android-info.txt`.

That text file has a couple lines in it, the last of which starts with `require version-baseband`. By adding `|D720SPRXXX` to the end, I was able to trick the update into accepting my device. I updated that text file in the .zip file, ran `flash-all.sh` again, and everything worked as it should!

My phone's working as I want it now, but I'd still like to know how in the world this happened in the first place. I'll leave this question open a while longer, and if anyone can explain what would cause a problem like this, I'll accept that answer.